# React js bundle size is 1.9mb

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to reduce my bundle.js size. Currently it's 1.9mb so is there any way by which i can reduce it as much as i can. I have done lazy loading and was able to reduce from 2.3mb to 1.9 mb.

Comment: If you also define the cache group for chunking vendor scripts. You can use webpack-budnle-analyzer to understand the bundle scripts and see what else can be lazily loaded or dynamically loaded --- https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Comment: Maybe an obvious one, but make sure you are doing a _production_ build...

Answer (score -1):

try compression to your bundling process, will reduce a lot of bundle size. This [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) can help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).